# Denotation of common nouns

Tags: semantics, nouns, pragmatics, denotation

Do common nouns have any singular 'denotation' or do all of them denote entirely contextually? For example in 'a car' is 'car' denoting a type of object  and the entire phrase describing an object of that type?

Do singular words like 'king' denote a specific role/office? Is there any rule for the denotation of common nouns after determiners?

Taking any philosophical views out of it, is there any lingusitic rules on the denotation of common nouns, or is it simply that they can be used to describe and may denote contextually a real object, for example in:

'men entered the room'

If I take the word 'man' does this have any particular denotation other than we use it to discuss real things of that type?

Answer (score 2):

The typical assumption is that common nouns denote a set of individuals, namely all those which satisfy the predicate in the given situation. E.g. the denotation of "king" in the real world right now is {King Charles III of GB, King Carl XVI. Gustav of Sweden, King Felipe VI. of Spain, King Vajiralongkorn of Thailand, ...}. (Note that the denotation is supposed to contain the real humans, not just names, I just can't put the real king Charles into an SE post so I have to resort to using words.) Similarly, "man" denotes the set of all real, concrete adult male humans.

Determiners such as "a", "the" or the empty indefinite plural determiner as in "men entered the room" then combine with these nouns to form phrases which have an open slot to plug in a predicate that also denotes a set of individuals (typically a verb, like "walks"), which results in a sentence that is true if a certain relation between the two predicates (as expressed by the determiner, e.g. there is at least one individual which is a member of both sets) holds. The details of this are too long for an SE post; I recommend E. Coppock & L. Champollion's [Semantics Boot Camp](https://eecoppock.info/bootcamp/semantics-boot-camp.pdf), ch. 6.3 (Quantifiers) for further reading.

Comment: Do you mean that the denotation of "man" right now is the set of all real, concrete adult male humans (bad example since "man" also denotes "human", but whatever)? And the denotation of "man" a month ago was a slightly different set?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Note that this presupposes the Axiom of Choice, which is independent.

Comment: @jlawler Why would that be?

Comment: _A man_ does not denote a set, but rather a member chosen from the set. It's only the generic noun that denotes a set.

Comment: @jlawler The assumption in standard textbook formal semantics (in the one I referred to anyway) is that "a man" denotes not a single individual, but a set of sets of individuals, namely all those which intersect with the set of men. For this you don't need a choice function. Do you have any reference for where your proposed denotation of "a man" is used?

Comment: How can " 'a man' denote not a single individual but a set of sets of individuals"? That's not even grammatical in English. If one is not politically correct, "man" is a set of all human individuals.

Comment: @Lambie What do you mean "it's not grammatical"? Denotations are not something that can be grammatical or ungrammatical. Only expressions can be. If you want to know more about how it works and why it makes sense, I suggest you read it up in the free book I linked.

Comment: "If one is not politically correct, "man" is a set of all human individuals." Right, it can have that meaning too. But that's consistent with what has been said earlier: The takeaway is that a common noun denotes a set of individuals; be it all humans, or only the male ones, or only the male royal ones.

Comment: ... And a common noun with determiner (such as "a man") is something else, clearly grammatically and as a consequence also semantically.

Comment: @NatalieClarius You wrote this: " 'a man' denote not a single individual but a set of sets of individuals". That sentence or phrase or utterance is not grammatical in English. I said nothing about denotation. I think my comment was clear.